# Elasticsearch aggregations by hour returning duplicate hours

Tags: elasticsearch

I did the following query in ES to return HOURS with more visits, based on field acctstarttime.

But as I have more than one day with the same HOUR it is returned the same HOUR 2x, when it was expected 1 result for HOUR with your COUNT.

**Query:**

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query": {
                    "match": { "client_id" : 1 }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "range" : {
                                "acctstarttime" : {
                                    "gte" : "2016-05-01 00:00:00",
                                    "lte" : "2016-06-02 23:59:59"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "visits_per_hour" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "acctstarttime",
                "interval" : "hour",
                "format" : "HH"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "visits_per_hour": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key_as_string": "17",
                "key": 1463763600000,
                "doc_count": 6
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "18",
                "key": 1463767200000,
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "22",
                "key": 1464127200000,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "22",
                "key": 1464300000000,
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "22",
                "key": 1464559200000,
                "doc_count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "visits_per_hour": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key_as_string": "17",
                "key": 1463763600000,
                "doc_count": 6
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "18",
                "key": 1463767200000,
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "22",
                "key": 1464127200000,
                "doc_count": 4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions

1. You add another field `hour` at indexing time and you aggregate on that field
2. You use a little `script` that will extract the hour and aggregate on it (note: you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting))

The first solution is the preferred one as it will be more performant.

The second solution looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "visits_per_hour": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": "doc.acctstarttime.date.getHourOfDay()",
        "interval": 1,
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```